# Dynamically create a generic type which use the type itself as generic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Here a dummy code to explain my problem:

```
public class A<TX, TA> where TA : A<TX, TA>
{

}

public void Do()
{
   var doy = typeof(A<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string), null/*??????*/));
}
```

How can I make a type from my generic type, if I can't identifty my type to use it as parameter?

Thanks for your help.

Edit, example of doing it statically:

```
public abstract class A<TX, TA> where TA : A<TX, TA>
{
    public TA ChainMethod()
    {
        return (TA)this;
    }
}

public class AConcrete : A<string, AConcrete>
{
    public AConcrete OtherMethod()
    {
    return this;
    }
}

public class App
{
    public static void Start()
    {
    new AConcrete().ChainMethod().ChainMethod().OtherMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the CRTP - it is going to get really ugly; how would you express it in C#? `A<string, A<string, A<string, A<string, ........` ?

Comment: You can't. But adding "dynamically" is a red herring -- it's not like there's any way to do  this *statically*. `A<string, ???>` -- how am I to expand the "???"? There must be a base somewhere. The class itself is legal, but you need at least one other class to bootstrap it. [Eric Lippert's comments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/) on this being confusing and possibly not achieving what you want remain valid regardless.

Comment: Can you explain a more high-level requirement?

Comment: @Andrei (and others), I added a sample on my initial post.

Comment: What part of that code would you like to do dynamically? Dynamically generate `AConcrete`? You will need it as a separate type regardless. You cannot call `.MakeGenericType` to pass it the very same type you're in the process of creating. You *can* generate a type that inherits from a generic type with itself as a type parameter, as the C# code is doing (use `ModuleBuilder.DefineType`) -- but that's creating a type at runtime, not merely instantiating a generic type.

Comment: Actually in my case, the AConcrete can exists, and my A is not abstract.
I want find the AConcrete if exists for my type TX, or, if not found, create a new type (A<TX,???>).

Maybe generate a new type as you said could be a solution, I was expecting easier :p

Comment: It's possible, but you'll still need `DefineType` in the latter case, and it sounds way more complicated than necessary. Consider some solution with generic methods of non-generic classes, those tend to be far simpler. Or some approach with a `Dictionary` of `Type`s to map things. Don't get too bogged down in generics -- type safety isn't much good once you're doing things at runtime anyway.

Comment: I'll try in this way, but I don't know how I will generate a type which reference itself, if I don't have a reference to this type yet...

Maybe I'll draw and add a workaround, like create a A<TX> which inherits from A<TX, A<TX>> :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to design your class hierarchy. It seems like it's not quite there yet. Please check out this example, hope it will give you an idea:

```
abstract class BaseBuilder<TBrick>
{
    public BaseBuilder<TBrick> AddBrick(TBrick brick)
    {
        // ...
        return this;
    }
}

class Builder : BaseBuilder<ConcreteBrick>
{
    public Builder AddRoof()
    {
        // ...
        return this;
    }

    public new Builder AddBrick(ConcreteBrick brick) 
    {
        base.AddBrick(brick);
        return this;
    }
}
```

And it will look like this:

```
new Builder()
    .AddBrick(new ConcreteBrick())
    .AddBrick(new ConcreteBrick())
    .AddRoof();
```

I think you won't be able to chain calls with inheritance if you don't override methods with `new` keyword like I suggested. Though you can implement things easily if you give up an idea of chaining calls.

Comment: There is no inheritance in your sample.

Comment: Nice try with your edit, but AddRoof() can't be call because the return type of AddBrick() is BaseBuilder<TBrick>, not "Builder" :)

Comment: @Manofgoa please see an update. I don't like `new` keyword there but this is the way you can get away with.

Comment: Yes, "new" keyword is a solution (used by WebForms to expose a strongly-typed MasterPage for instance).

But my point is to minimize code that developpers which will inherit from my base class will write.

Comment: @Manofgoa I think you won't be able to chain calls with inheritance if don't override methods with `new` like I suggested. Though you can implement things easily if you give up an idea of chaining calls.

Comment: You can see a sample of use in the first post (edited), but it's static :(